# Existence of Shafarevich maps(theorem 3.6) on Kollar 's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, abelian-varieties

I have some problem when reading Theorem 3.6 of Kollar's book  Shafarevich Maps and Automorphic Forms, page 41 (Corollary 3.5 of [this article](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/597/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01244307.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01244307&token2=exp=1435653990~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F597%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF01244307.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF01244307*~hmac=a9f1386f5c5884d005e8144de5679897b3db7928d60f53a103128c249b4537a6) ), which states that

Let $X$ be a normal variety, $H\triangleleft \pi_1(X)$ a normal subgroup. Then

(i) there are open subsets $X^0\subset X$ and $Z^0\subset Sh^H(X)$ such that the H-shafarevich map $sh_X^H:X^0\to Z^0$ is everywhere defined,

(ii) every fiber of $sh_X^H|X^0$ is closed in $X$, and

(iii) $sh_X^H|X^0$ is a  toplogically locally trivial fibration.

**Here is a sketch:**  Pick $x\in VG(X)$, $w_0:W_0\to X$ normal cycle of maximal dimension, and $im[\pi_1(W_0)\to \pi_1(X)]\lesssim H$. we can find a locally topologically trivial family of normal cycles   $S\longleftarrow W\longrightarrow X$  which contains $W_0$ such that $\text{im}\,w_s\ne \text{im}\, w_{s'}$. Our aim is to prove that the existence of $S^0\subset S$ such that $w: p^{-1}(S^0)\to X$ is an open immersion.

because a very general point of $X$ has only one pre image in $W$, therefore $w$ is birational. Let the $D_w$ be closed subset which is not immersion. Then   it says that we can find $S_0$ and $D_s$ which is disjoint. Finally the proof ends with some settings.

**My problem is**:  Why can't $D_w$  cover all of W?
Why can we find the open set? Why can't the bad things cover all of $S$?

Comment: Though the reference might be accurate (actually different editions can have differently-indexed theorems), this site prefers self-sufficient posts, when not absolutely necessary. Pease, write it so that one does not need to go to the library to understand the notation and/or find the passage.

Comment: Maybe it's good to link to the [open-access copy](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002111101&IDDOC=181607) of the paper. It's amazing that Springer will still charge you $40 for such things. It's probably asking too much for a question like this to be self-contained.